# How to get a encrypted folder with passphrase

Tags: 11.10, encryption, folder

I have some data that I want to encrypt in a single folder. I only need it rarely, so I would like to be asked for a pass phrase every time.

Preferably I could still back up the folder encrypted, and open it with the passphrase on another machine.

What approach shall I take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a graphical interface that integrates well with gnome, try cryptkeeper.

The home page is here : http://tom.noflag.org.uk/cryptkeeper.html

It is in the ubuntu repositories.

Other options include Truecrypt, ecryptfs, and LUKS.

ecryptfs is also in the ubuntu repository,and should be installed by default, If it is not:

```
sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils
```

Make an encrypted directory, **to be decrytped when you log in** with

```
ecryptfs-setup-private
```

To make a directory that is not automatically decrypted when you log in you will need root access

```
mkdir ~/secret
chmod 700 secret
```

Encrypt the directory

```
sudo mount -t ecryptfs ~your_user/secret ~your_user/secret
```

You will be asked to enter a passphrase and a number of additional questions. Go with the defaults (hit enter) but answer y (yes) to "Enable filename encryption (y/n) [n]:" to encrypt file names.

Place any data you wish encrypted in ~/secret .

To encrypt the data

```
sudo umount ./secret
```

To decrypt the data, mount the directory again

To make it easier you can give the options you desire to the mount command with the -o flag (all one line)

```
sudo mount ~your_user/secret~your_user/secret -o key=passphrase,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_passthrough=no,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=yes
```

Either make an alias in ~/.bashrc or make a custom launcher.